# Constrain with conditional value check in MySQL

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique-constraint, unique-key, unique-index

I need to add a combinational and value based Constrain check

My Table Structure is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ContactPhone` (
  `ContactPhoneId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ContactId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PhoneId` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `ContactPhone`
--
ALTER TABLE `ContactPhone`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ContactPhoneId`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `ContactPhone`
--
ALTER TABLE `ContactPhone`
  MODIFY `ContactPhoneId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
  AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I need to ensure the record based on the following **combinational conditional constrain**

- `ContactId`
- `PhoneId`
- `Status == 1` (value should be 1 - Active Record)

Note: No need of the In-active Records (i.e., `Status == 0`). I need this constrain only for the Active Records.

Kindly assist me how to add this constrain for the above motioned MySQL Table.

Comment: A constraint is a condition. E.g. `not null` is a contraint. So you have to be more precise on what you want to check for these columns. I assume you mean e.g. a foreign key constraint? For example, "If Status is 1, the combination `ContactId, PhoneId` has to exists in table xy if Status is 1 (and if Status is 0, they can have any value)" or "If Status is 1, `ContactId` has to exist in table x and `PhoneId` has to exist in table y"). Btw, if you mean what I think you mean, it sounds like a bad idea, and you are probably better off setting nonexisting values to `null`.

Comment: @Solarflare - the combination of all three column should be `UNIQUE`. This `UNIQUE` Check only need to work for an Active Records (i.e., `Status == 1`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html),

> A UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.

So removing the `not null`-constraint from `Status` and adding a unique index on `(ContactId,PhoneId,Status)` will work as you want it to, if you use `null` instead of `0` for *inactive* records.

If you don't want to or cannot use `null` for your `Status` column, want to make sure both `Status=0` and `Status=null` behave identically, or e.g. want to treat `Status=2` as *active* (and enforcing uniqueness) too, you can add a dummy column that will be calculated from `Status`.

If you are using MySQL 5.7+, you can do this with a generated column:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ContactPhone` (
  `ContactPhoneId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
  `ContactId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PhoneId` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `StatusUnq` tinyint(1) as (if(Status <> 0, 1, null)) stored null,
  constraint unique (ContactId, PhoneId, StatusUnq)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into ContactPhone (ContactPhoneId, ContactId, PhoneId, Status)
values (1, 1, 1, 1);
insert into ContactPhone (ContactPhoneId, ContactId, PhoneId, Status)
values (2, 1, 1, 1);
-- Duplicate key error 
insert into ContactPhone (ContactPhoneId, ContactId, PhoneId, Status)
values (3, 1, 1, 0);
insert into ContactPhone (ContactPhoneId, ContactId, PhoneId, Status)
values (4, 1, 1, 0);
update ContactPhone set Status = 1 where ContactPhoneId = 4;
-- Duplicate key error
```

Otherwise, you can use a normal column and use triggers to calculate the value of the column, e.g.:

```
create trigger trbi_contactPhoneUnique before insert on ContactPhone 
for each row
  set new.StatusUnq = if(new.Status <> 0, 1, null);

create trigger trbu_contactPhoneUnique before update on ContactPhone 
for each row
  set new.StatusUnq = if(new.Status <> 0, 1, null);
```

You can of course switch the formula to e.g. `if(new.Status <> 0, new.Status, null);` if you want to allow different values of `Status` too.