# INSERT based on the relationship between the types of entities to be inserted?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't find a term for what I'm trying to do so that may be limiting my ability to find info related to my question.

I'm trying to relate product identifiers and product processing codes (orange table in fig.) with validation against what product types and subtypes are valid for each process code based on process type. Importantly, each product identifier is related to a product type (see `ProductIdentifier` table) and each process code is related to process type (see `ProcessCode` table). I minimized the attributes in the tables below to only those necessary for my question.

[image]

In the above example, when I `INSERT INTO` the `RunProcessTypeOne` table, I need to validate that the `ProductCode` for `RoleOneProductIdentifier` is present in `ProductTypeTwo`. Similarly, I need to validate that the `ProductCode` for `RoleTwoProductIdentifier` is present in `ProductSubtypeOne`.

Of course I can use a stored procedure that inserts into the `RunProcessTypeOne` table after running `SELECT` to check for the presence of the `ProductCode` related to `RoleOneProductIdentifier` and `RoleTwoProductIdentifier` in the relevant tables. This doesn't seem optimal since I'm having to run three `SELECT`s for every `INSERT`. Plus, it seems fishy that the relationship between `ProcessType`s and `ProductCode`s would only be known within the stored procedure and not via relationships established between the tables themselves (foreign key).

Are there alternatives to this approach? Is there a standard for handling this type of validation where you need to validate individual instances (e.g. `ProductIdentifiers`) of entity types based on the relationships between those types (e.g. the relationship between `ProductTypeTwo` and `ProcessTypeOne`)?

If more details are helpful: The relationship between `ProductCode` and `ProcessCode` is many-to-many but there are rules that define product roles in each process and only certain product types or subtypes may fulfill those roles. `ProductTypeOne` might include attributes that define a specific kind of product like color or shape. `ProductIdentifier` includes the many lots of any `ProductCode` that are manufactured. `ProcessCode` includes settings that are put on a machine for processing. `ProductType` by way of `ProductCode` determines if a `ProductIdentifier` is valid for a particular `ProcessType`. Individual `ProcessCode`s don't discriminate valid `ProducIdentifier`s, only the `ProcessType` related to the `ProcessCode` would discriminate.

Comment: Have you looked into conditional constraints? Sounds like this question to me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867149/constrain-with-conditional-value-check-in-mysql

Comment: Why do you have both `ProductCode` and `ProductIdentifier`/what's the difference between them? Why is table `RunProcessTypeOne` using `ProductIdentifier` as FK/couldn't it use `ProductCode`? It looks to me like `ProductCode` is the main way to relate info for a Product(?) whereas `ProductIdentifier`s are some sort of 'alternative keys'(?) Perhaps not all Products have a `ProductIdentifier` whereas `ProductCode` is a stable key(?) Then `RunProcessTypeOne` should have a FK to `ProductCode` _not_ `ProductIdentifier`.

Comment: @AntC `ProductIdentifier` includes the individual instances of a `ProductCode`. Say I produce two wood blocks per specifications for `ProductCode` = "jie530". Each of those wood blocks has an individual `ProductIdentifier`, say "123" and "456". `RunProcessTypeOne` must include `ProductIdentifier` because there are values unique to each `ProductIdentifier`, e.g. date made, operator, air temp, weight. All products have both a `ProductCode` and `ProductIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it seems fishy that the relationship between `ProcessTypes` and `ProductCodes` would only be known within the stored procedure and not via relationships established between the tables themselves (foreign key).

Yes that's an important observation, good to see you questioning the current schema. The fact of the matter is that SQL is not very powerful when it comes to representing data structures. So often a stored procedure is the only/least worst approach.

I'll make a suggestion for how to achieve this without stored procedures, but I won't call it "optimal": there's likely to be a performance hit for `INSERT`s (and worse for `UPDATE`s), because the SQL engine will probably be in effect carrying out the same `SELECT`s as you'd code in a stored procedure.

Split table `ProductIdentifier` into two:

- `ProductIdentifierTypeTwo` PK `ProductIdentifier`, `ProductCode` FK `REFERENCES` `ProductTypeTwo.ProductCode`.
- `ProductIdentifierTypeOne` PK `ProductIdentifier`, `ProductCode` FK `REFERENCES` `ProductTypeOne.ProductCode`.
- Also `CREATE VIEW` `ProductIdentifier` `UNION` the two sub-tables, PK `ProductIdentifier`. This makes sure `ProductIdentifier` isn't duplicated between the two types.

IOW this avoids the `ProductIdentifier` table directly referencing the `ProductCode` table, where it can only examine `ProductType` as a column value, not as a referential structure.

Then

- `RunProcessTypeOne.RoleOneProductIdentifier` FK `REFERENCES` `ProductIdentifierTypeTwo.ProductIdentifier`.
- `RunProcessTypeOne.RoleTwoProductIdentifier` FK `REFERENCES` `ProductIdentifierTypeOne.ProductIdentifier`.

Making the original `ProductIdentifier` a `VIEW` is the least non-optimal way to manage updates (I'm guessing from your comment): `ProductIdentifiers` are less volatile than `RunProcess`es.

Re your more general question:

> Is there a standard for handling this type of validation where you need to validate individual instances (e.g. `ProductIdentifiers`) of entity types based on the relationships between those types (e.g. the relationship between `ProductTypeTwo` and `ProcessTypeOne`)?

There are facilities included in the SQL standard. Most vendors haven't implemented them, or only partially support them -- essentially because implementing them would need running `SELECT`s with tricky logic as part of table updates.

- You should be able to `CREATE VIEW` with a filter to only the rows that are the target of some FK.
  (Your dba is likely to object that `VIEW`s come with an unacceptable performance hit. In this example, you'd have a single `ProductIdentifier` table, with the two sub-tables I suggest above as `VIEW`s. But maintaining those views would need joining to `ProductCode` to filter by `ProductType`.)
- Then you should be able to define a FK to the `VIEW` rather than to the base table.
  (This is the bit many SQL vendors don't support.)

Comment: Thanks. I don't think MySQL will let me FK to a `VIEW`. I do need a table that includes all `ProductIdentifiers` since some `RunProcess` have a single role (attribute) that accepts any `ProductType`. To resolve this, I could have a base table `ProductIdentifier` with the subtype tables that you suggested but like this: `ProductIdentifierTypeTwo` PK,FK `ProductIdentifier` `REFERENCES` `ProductIdentifier.ProductIdentifier`, `ProductCode` FK `REFERENCES` `ProductTypeTwo.ProductCode`. I didn't think of this since common attributes, e.g.`ProductCode`, are typically stored in the base table.